# FreePascal: Trouble with unit conversions.

Tags: type-conversion, freepascal

When I compile the following code, I get errors. I don't understand some of them.

**Code**

```
program Lasagna;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Classes, SysUtils
  { you can add units after this };

{$R *.res}
type
  TVehicle = record
    kindOfVehicle : String[30];
    numberOfWheels : Integer;
    horsePower : Real;
  end;

var
  F: file of TVehicle;
  Vehicle : Array [1..3] of TVehicle;
  index : Integer;

begin
     writeln('A RECORD OF DIFFERENT KIND OF VEHICLES.');
     writeln('---------------------------------------');
     writeln;

     AssignFile(F,'C:/Users/W/Desktop/CarRecord.dat');
     writeln('Searching for file.');
     if FileExists('C:/Users/W/Desktop/CarRecord.dat') then
        begin
          writeln('File found. Opening file.');
          Rewrite(F);
          writeln('File ready.');
          writeln;
          writeln;

          for index:=0 to 3 do
          begin
            writeln('Enter the following details for vehicle no. ',index);
            write('Kind of Vehicle: ');
            readln(Vehicle[index].kindOfVehicle);
            write(F,Vehicle[index].kindOfVehicle);//line 45: this is a string so why do I get an error?**

            {Do NOT use writeln() when writing to random access files.}

            write('Number of Wheels: ');
            readln(Vehicle[index].numberOfWheels);
            write(F,IntToStr(Vehicle[index].numberOfWheels));//line 51: The int is converted to string, so i shouldn't get an error?

            write('Horse Power of Vehicle: ');
            readln(Vehicle[index].horsePower);
            write(F, RealToStr(Vehicle[index].horsePower));//line 55:  
            end;

          writeln('Done. Closing File.');
          CloseFile(F);
        end
     else
         Rewrite(F);
         CloseFile(F);
         writeln('File Not Found.');

     Writeln('Press ANY key to close the program.');
     Readln;
end.
```

**Errors**

> Compiling Lasagna.lpr
>
> Lasagna.lpr(45,49) Error: Incompatible types: got "ShortString"
>   expected "TVehicle"
>
> Lasagna.lpr(51,60) Error: Incompatible types: got "AnsiString"
>   expected "TVehicle"
>
> Lasagna.lpr(55,59) Error: Incompatible types: got "AnsiString"
>   expected "TVehicle"
>
> Lasagna.lpr(70) Fatal: There were 3 errors compiling module, stopping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 21, you are declaring F as "file of TVehicle". So, you should write TVehicle data to it, not strings.

Comment: I understand that but how do I convert the String to TVehicle? Thanks.

Comment: After you have done the 3rd readln, Vehicle[index] contains the full record. At that point you can just do `write(F, Vehicle[index]);` (and omit all the previous writes).

Comment: Oh my God, that seems so obvious now! Shoulda thoughta that. I was thinking along the lines of Java and thought I'd have to so some casting or something. Thanks a lot for your help. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In these 3 cases you try to write a string into F which is declared as a file of TVehicle, so the compiler is right.

To fix it, you should read each field into a variable of the right type, fill a TVehicle type variable with those, or use the fields of the TVehicle structure directly and write that variable to the file.  Something along these lines (my Pascal is getting a bit rusty, chances are this doesn't compile without touching it up):

```
var intermediateVehicle : TVehicle;
....
write('Kind of Vehicle: ');
readln(intermediateVehicle.kindOfVehicle);
write('Number of Wheels: ');
readln(intermediateVehicle.numberOfWheels);
write('Horse Power of Vehicle: ');
readln(intermediateVehicle.horsePower);
write(F,intermediateVehicle);
```

Of course, error checking still has to be added...

Comment: That makes sense! Is there a way to fix this? I'm still getting the hang of freePascal?